# How to automate backup downloads between two Ubuntu 14.04 servers

Tags: 14.04, backup, cron

I have two Ubuntu 14.04, one is for production and one is for backup.

On the production server, I have a folder with backups automatically generated by a `cron` job. How can I make the backup server connect to that folder and download the files every day securely?

They're two separate servers on a different network.

Comment: Check this question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/28491/how-to-download-ubuntu-server-backups-automatically?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use rsync as a means to achieve synchronizing a folder on your backup server with a folder on the main server.

to install rsync if you don't have:

```
sudo apt install rsync
```

also, you can use  cron jobs to automate the whole process of backup;

here's a simple way to make it work, just add this to the cron in the production server:

```
0 0 * * * rsync -avh /proction_server_directory/ user@backup_server_IP:/backup_directory/
```

this will sync the contents on the proction_server_directory to the backup_directory every midnight.

also make sure to add your production server's public key to the backup server's known hosts